# Selecting top 10 data from one table and inserting into other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

PSeudo Code:

```
Create Procedure SP_GetAllData
(@Count,@EmailID)
Create table #tempTable
(
  Id Int Not Null Identity (1,1)
  Message nvarchar (max)
)

Insert into SecondTable
(EmailID,Message,Subject,MessageID,)
(@EmailID,'Select Message from #tempTable','Message Subjest','Select ID from #tempTable')
```

How to insert the data into temptable and then into second table?

Here in the above statement i want to insert both the records from FirstTable into SecondTable along with its existing columns

Comment: So just do select ... from FirstTable in the insert? Or maybe #tempTable, which seems quite pointless here. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: I have done as per shown but the problem is I want to insert the data in second table from first one but what about other column of Second table

Comment: And First table is having lots of data in that.So would that be propogated to second table along with the other column

Comment: If the data for the other columns is not in the variable or firstData, where are you planning to get it? If it's in either of those, just include it in the select clause

Comment: As shown there is 4 columns,out of which one is getting filled by @EmailID and Other Column is literal and other 2 are from first table

Comment: Yes, so what is the problem? Just do insert into ... select [the 4 columns / variables here] from #tempTable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting top 10 data from one table and inserting into other table using SP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905439/selecting-top-10-data-from-one-table-and-inserting-into-other-table-using-sp)

Comment: Insert into SecondTable (EmailID,[Message], [Subject] ,MessageID)
Select top (@Count) @EmailID,[Message], [Subject] ,ID  
from FirstTable

Comment: @JamesZ Please look at the Comment

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Hopefully someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something what you need, you do not need a temp table for this operation anyway,  but you do need to order by some column otherwise TOP Clause without an ORDER BY is pretty meaningless.

```
Create Procedure SP_GetAllData
  @Count    INT
 ,@EmailID  INT
AS
BEGIN 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

Insert into SecondTable (EmailID,[Message], [Subject] ,MessageID)
Select top (@Count) @EmailID,[Message], [Subject] ,ID  
from FirstTable
-- ORDER BY SomeColumn

END
```